# Removing Parts of File names in Folder

Tags: java, file, stringbuffer, substring

The code below works, but my problem is that the console output shows correctly for example:

```
3-M-ALABAMA-SUIQUARTER2
3-M-ALABAMA-SUIQUARTER2
3-M-ALABAMAW-22017
3-M-ALABAMAW-22017
```

The output above show that my index is -2017 however when the actual file name is being change in the folder some of the File Names are skipped. For example

Orginal file name: `3-M-ALABAMA-SUIQUARTER2-2017200346-CD6140`
Console Output: `3-M-ALABAMA-SUIQUARTER2`
Some of Files in folder unchanged: `3-M-ALABAMA-SUIQUARTER2-2017200346-CD6140`

However some of the files in the folder have `3-M-BATTLECREEKMIW-22017-2017200346-CD619B` and some are `3-M-ARLINGTONOHLOCALW-2-2017200346-CD61A8`

So I think java is confused as to where to cut off when the actual change is being made in file alteration? can you help me?

```
for(File file:filesInDir) {
       x++;
       String name = file.getName().substring(0, file.getName().indexOf("-2017"));
       String newName = name;
       System.out.println(newName); // prints prints to file 
       String newPath = absolutePathOne + "\\" + newName;
       file.renameTo(new File(newPath));
}
```

Comment: I even used the substring method  String name = file.getName().substring(0,20);
and still it does the same thing not all file names in folder are changed

Comment: Is there a way to get past this? Sub-string and Index-of are not working for me in this case,

Comment: what you are trying to achieve is to remove the -2017xxxx- pattern from the original filename?

Comment: actually I am trying to remove everything from -2017 and back yes

Comment: file.renameTo is not guaranteed to work. It returns a boolean false if it failed.

Comment: Okay good to know however is there another alternative to remove everything from -2017 and back?

Comment: renameTo won't work if permissions are required

Comment: Okay permission are not an issues here. As far as I know.

Comment: Okay there any other way to rename the files? I am using a windows 10 laptop.

Comment: I guess you may consider to create a new file with the original contents and removing the old one.

Comment: I guess what I am thinking is that I can rename the files in the folder using a similar method but when it comes to removing part of a name there is a problem.

Comment: I implemented the below solution and it corrects the 1st 2 file names but then stops and gives me a java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException

Comment: Okay all I found what the issue and my code works properly now was I was using the same folder to retrieve the file names and change them i used a different folder for the output and it worked. file.renameTo(new File(newPath)) worked as well 
-----------------
however the  Files.move(file.toPath(), Paths.get(newPath)) still had an exception in eclipse for some reason still researching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [Okay there any other way to rename the files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45174365/removing-parts-of-file-names-in-folder#comment77318059_45174365)

Yes. Use the newer NIO 2 classes, in particular the [`Files.move()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-) method.

At the very least, replace `file.renameTo(new File(newPath))` with:

```
Files.move(file.toPath(), Paths.get(newPath));
```

That will throw descriptive exception if move fails, instead of the `false` boolean return value from [`renameTo()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo-java.io.File-).

You should also change the rest of the code to use the newer classes. Although not required, it is recommended to do so.

Comment: is that File.move from guava?

Comment: @assembler Click the link. It's built-in Java 7+.

Comment: Okay I replaced the line and I get a red line under (move) in eclipse

Comment: @JonathanHofler Oops. `Files`, not `File`.

Comment: I made that change butnow i am getting:
for some reason i am getting Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException: C:\Users\hoflerj\Desktop\After\3-M-ALABAMA-SUIQUARTER2

Comment: some of the file name have the same or similar begging characters

Comment: Is it possible to continue this in chat?

Comment: Okay all I found what the issue and my code works properly now was I was using the same folder to retrieve the file names and change them i used a different folder for the output and it worked. file.renameTo(new File(newPath)) worked as well 

however the  Files.move(file.toPath(), Paths.get(newPath)) still had an exception in eclipse for some reason still researching.

Comment: actually after taking a deeper look not all renameTo is not working