# Renaming Files renameTo() workaround Java

Tags: java, eclipse, file-io

The following code file.renameTo(new File(newPath)); dosen't rename all the files properly it skips over some I have even used  Files.move(file.toPath(), Paths.get(newPath)); but i get an exception error in eclipse saying java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException which i think is occurring because there are sets of files that when they are cut off they will have the same name is there a way to bypass this error in eclipse or fine tune the renameTo()?

I also have tried .substring(0,22);, name.replaceFirst("-2017.*", ""); and
name.substring(0, file.getName().indexOf("-2017") same result.

example:
orginal file name: 3-M-ALABAMA-SUIQUARTER2-2017200346-CD6140
Console Output: 3-M-ALABAMA-SUIQUARTER2
some of Files in folder unchanged: 3-M-ALABAMA-SUIQUARTER2-2017200346-CD6140

```
for(File file:filesInDir) {
       String name = file.getName().substring(0, file.getName().indexOf("-2017"));
       String newName = name;
       System.out.println(newName); // prints prints to file 
       String newPath = absolutePathOne + "\\" + newName;
       file.renameTo(new File(newPath));
       or
       Files.move(file.toPath(), Paths.get(newPath));
```

Comment: This question is very hard to read, and you're going to have to be a whole lot clearer.  What do you mean by "when they are cut off"?  What's an example of a file you're trying to rename?  What's the file that's preventing it from being renamed?

Comment: an example is orginal file name: 3-M-ALABAMA-SUIQUARTER2-2017200346-CD6140
Console Output: 3-M-ALABAMA-SUIQUARTER2
some of Files in folder unchanged: 3-M-ALABAMA-SUIQUARTER2-2017200346-CD6140

Comment: I added additional information

Comment: So is there already a file in the destination folder with the new name?

Comment: what i mean my cut off is that I am trying to take out everything from -2017xxx

Comment: Are you saying that you have several files that you're trying to rename to the same thing?

Comment: well when use Files.move(file.toPath(), Paths.get(newPath)); 1 new name is generated but then i get ( java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException )

Comment: well no i trying to rename by cutting off or takeing off everything after the -2017xxx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149541/discussion-between-jonathan-hofler-and-dawood-ibn-kareem).

Comment: Well, that exception is telling you you've already used that name.  What do you want your program to do when two different files have names that start off the same (up until the 2017 part)?  Also, how is this different from the question you asked almost 9 hours ago?

Comment: To simplify question, you have 2 files named `A1` and `A2` and you want to strip the digit, so you rename `A1` to `A` (all good), then you try to rename `A2` to `A` and you're confused that it fails? And you ask how to "bypass" the error? What do you expect such a "bypass" to do, since you cannot have two files with the same name? Your question is meaningless, and a duplicate of [Removing Parts of File names in Folder](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45174365/5221149).

Comment: Well when I did further testing and thought i resolved the issue but i did not also I wanted further incite on the File.move ability since it seemed renameTo() did not work and how to get past the  issue with files.move

Comment: To "get past the issue" you need to figure out what you want to do when another file by that name already exists. Leave things alone (don't rename), or replace the existing file? We can't tell you what to do, because it's *your* decision what you want result to be. --- You could rename to an alternate name, but that is again up to you to decide to do that, and to come up with a naming scheme.

Comment: @Andreas well in programming I have learned there has always been a work around or an alternative way of doing things i though there could be a work around to the exception. however if there is not workaround then it is what it is

Comment: You need to decide _what_ you want your program to do, before you ask the Stack Overflow community _how_ to make it do that.  This isn't a programming question - this is a "Jonathan needs to make up his mind" question.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem- Well when another file has the same name I desire it to do the same thing take everything off from -2017xxx in other words i want it to be renamed in the same way as the one before it.. I apologize I though I made that clear when i stated my question.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I apologize I thought that I stated my question correctly basically I am not getting the desired result in renaming all the files in the folder which is cutting off the -2017xxx what I have done is shown above any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not rename a particular file to a file name that already exists within the folder you are renaming the file in. IMHO ... Even if you can, you shouldn't for a bunch of common sense reasons.

In other words, if we have a folder (directory) named: `All_My_Files` and in this folder we have two text files, one is named `MyFile-2016.txt` and the other is named `MyFile-2017.txt`. Now, we want to rename each of these two files so that the dash and the year (ie: -2016 or -2017) from each file name no longer exists. Essentially what you will end up trying to do is have both file names be **MyFile.txt** which is not allowed. Your first rename will be fine since on the first go at it there is no file within the folder named **MyFile.txt** but once the second rename attempt is done on the second file name it's simply going to fail since the name **MyFile.txt** already exists within that folder which was done from the first rename attempt. This not a code problem, this is an issue with the local file system. Those are the rules of the local file system (No file can have the same name within the same folder). Look at the file names you are going to rename, are there any that will actually create the very same file name once you remove the unwanted text? If there are then those will fail to rename.

The same applies to Moving files. You can not **move** a file to a folder (directory) that already contains a file with the very same name. The file system rule above applies. You can however overwrite the existing duplicate file name within the destination path if it exists during a move **if** you tell the ***Files.move()*** method to do so:

```
Files.move(sourcePathAndFileName, destinationPathAndFileName,
           StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

You will need to import:

**import static java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING;**

Keep in mind though, before you blatantly overwrite an existing file you better make pretty sure that this is what you want to do. Prompting the User to carry out an overwrite would be a normal course of action but doesn't necessarily need to be the case for specific in house operations.